# How to convert this Perl Skript (Sipgate API) into Objective C / Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

does anyone have a small sample how to comunicate with the Sipgate Webservice in ObjC?
I´ve never used Webservices at all and I didn´t get it.
Here is a small Perl Skript, provided by Sipgate, on how to send SMS with their Webservice:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Sam Buca, indigo networks GmbH, 08/2007
#
# This script is a very basic perl-client to the SAMURAI service 
# provided by sipgate (indigo networks GmbH) without any claim to 
# completeness and without any warranty!
#
# The following code shows how to use the service to send messages 
# via SMS using a sipgate account.
#

use strict;
use Frontier::Client;   # needed for XMLRPC

# declare some variables for later use:
my $VERSION = "1.0";
my $NAME    = "sipgateAPI-sms.pl";
my $VENDOR  = "indigo networks GmbH";
my $url;
my $xmlrpc_client;
my $xmlrpc_result;
my $args_identify;
my $args;

# check the count of commandline parameters and show usage information 
# if not matching:
unless (@ARGV == 4) {
    print "\n";
    print "This script needs 4 parameters supplied on the commandline:\n";
    print "\n";
    print "parameter 1 -> the username (not SIPID) used to login to sipgate\n";
    print "parameter 2 -> the password associated with the username\n";
    print "parameter 3 -> the number to send the message to\n";
    print "               (with national prefix, e.g. 4917xxxxxxxxx)\n";
    print "parameter 4 -> the message to send quoted in \" or \'\n";
    print "\n";

    exit 0;
}

# define URL for XMLRPC:

$url = "https://$ARGV[0]:$ARGV[1]\@samurai.sipgate.net/RPC2";

# create an instance of the XMLRPC-Client:

$xmlrpc_client = Frontier::Client->new( 'url' => $url );

# identify the script to the server calling XMLRPC-method "samurai.ClientIdentify"
# providing client-name, -version and -vendor:

$args_identify = { ClientName => $NAME, ClientVersion => $VERSION, ClientVendor => $VENDOR };

$xmlrpc_result = $xmlrpc_client->call( "samurai.ClientIdentify", $args_identify );

# the check for success is not necessary in this case since the Frontier::Client module 
# dies with an exception in case of a fault, but we do it for completeness:

if ($xmlrpc_result->{'StatusCode'} == 200) {
    print "Successfully identified to the server!\n";
} else {
    # we should never get here!
    print "There was an error during identification to the server!\n";
}

# create the input argument set for XMLRPC:

$args = { RemoteUri => "sip:$ARGV[2]\@sipgate.net", TOS => "text", Content => $ARGV[3] };

# do the call and store the result / answer to $xmlrpc_result:

$xmlrpc_result = $xmlrpc_client->call( "samurai.SessionInitiate", $args );

# again we do the check on success for completeness:

if ($xmlrpc_result->{'StatusCode'} == 200) {
    print "Your request was successfully send to the server!\n";
} else {
    # we should never get here!
    print "There was an error!\n";
}
```

Can anyone show me how to send an SMS in ObjC with this Webservice? Don´t get me wrong, I don´t mean a full working code sample, just an explanation on how to do it! To be more precise, I don´t know how the request, the URL String has to look like!
In the Hillegass AmaZone Example, he creates an URL String as a request for the Amazon Webservice.

Thank you so much

twickl

Comment: Thank you for formatting the code! Tried it now for minutes and couldn´t get it right in the Editor. It´s much to hot today...or is it my brain.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a NSMutableURLRequest:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://…"]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:5.0];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:@"http body…"];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (!theConnection) {
    // Error…
}
```

and set the http body to the required xml message. To find out how that message has to look like, use the debug option of the Frontier client (http://metacpan.org/pod/Frontier::Client).

Then implement the necessary Delegate Methods in your class. In your case I think the didReceiveResponse is sufficient as you dont't want to read more complex data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection  *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)theResponse {
    if ([theRresponse statusCode] == 200) {
        // Everything is fine…
    }
}
```

Good luck!
cmitt